# Array with simple object failure

Tags: arrays, object

I am trying to fill an array with an object of type Person. (Person contains String lastname and firstname and an ID of typ integer)

After filling the Array, ill try to print the whole array. But it always prints me the last name i entered "x" times... I tried the same method with an array containing integers, and it works.
Maybe some of you have a clue whats going wrong there?

Here is the code snipplet:

```
public class Tester {

public static void Test() {
    int i=0, counter = 0, idx = 0;

    Person[] TestArray = new Person[3];
    Person testperson = new Person();
    testperson.lastname = "";
    testperson.firstname = "";
    testperson.id = 0;
    TestArray[0] = testperson;
    TestArray[1] = testperson;
    TestArray[2] = testperson;

    for (i = 0 ; i < TestArray.length; i++) {       
        //TestArray[i] = testperson;
        TextIO.put("Enter name: ");
    TestArray[i].lastname = TextIO.getln();
    }

    TextIO.put("Array contains: \n");

    for (i = 0 ; i < TestArray.length; i++) {
        TextIO.putf("%s ", TestArray[i].lastname);      
    }
```

...
...
...

And the output looks like:

Enter name: firstname

Enter name: secondname

Enter name: thirdname

Array contains: 
thirdname 
thirdname 
thirdname 
find:

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

maybe a forgetfulness

the

```
  Person testperson
```

is always the same instance referenced three times. **Every time you change the same object.**

consider the following code

```
Person testperson = new Person();
testperson.lastname = "";
testperson.firstname = "";
testperson.id = 0;
TestArray[0] = testperson;

testperson = new Person();
testperson.lastname = "";
testperson.firstname = "";
testperson.id = 1;
TestArray[1] = testperson;

testperson = new Person();
testperson.lastname = "";
testperson.firstname = "";
testperson.id = 2;
TestArray[2] = testperson;
```

or better use constructor to initialize `Person`.
Finally let me suggets to use **CamelCase notation**: `TestArray` is a variable but "it seems a Class"; `testArray` should be better

Comment: thanks for the good advice! this points out the problem... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is because all of the array cells are pointing to the same place.
You will need to use `new Person()` in order to create a new instance for every cell.

Also, keep the initialization inside your Constructor and not by manually unless you need it.

Remove

```
Person testperson = new Person();
testperson.lastname = "";
testperson.firstname = "";
testperson.id = 0;
```

Change the array assignment to create a new instance for every cell.

```
TestArray[0] = new Person();
TestArray[1] = new Person();
TestArray[2] = new Person();
```

Add to the `Person` constructor class the following:

```
public Person()
{
    lastname = string.Empty();
    firstname = string.Empty();
    id = 0;
}
```

Also i would highly recommend you to use naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the array is pointing to a single object. You need to make a `new Person()` for every new person.

As is now, `TestArray[0]`, `TestArray[1]`, and `TestArray[2]`, are all equal. So if you change one of them it changes all the others (hence why only the last entered name is shown).

Comment: Yes! *facepalm*Thanks for the prompt answer!